# Microsoft Office 2007 file type, Mime types and identifying characters

Tags: mime, file-type, office-2007

Where can I find a list of all of the MIME types and the identifying characters for **Microsoft Office 2007** files?

I have an upload form that is restricting uploads based on the extensions and identifying characters, but I cannot seem to find the **Office 2007 MIME** types.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 26):

[Office 2007 MIME Types for IIS](http://www.bram.us/2007/05/25/office-2007-mime-types-for-iis/)

- `.docm`, application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
- `.docx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- `.dotm`, application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
- `.dotx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
- `.potm`, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
- `.potx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
- `.ppam`, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
- `.ppsm`, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
- `.ppsx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
- `.pptm`, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
- `.pptx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
- `.xlam`, application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
- `.xlsb`, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
- `.xlsm`, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
- `.xlsx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
- `.xltm`, application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
- `.xltx`, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template